# how to put the name of a dataset as a column in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a very basic question in SAS. for example, if the dataset called 'a', how can I put 'a' as a new column into this dataset?
Thank you very much

Comment: More context would lead to a better answer.  Why do you want to do this?  Are you in a macro context, for example, or in a merge, or a set/union, or something else?  Why you're doing it affects the answer.

Comment: @Joe yes. I was trying to write a macro. The Marco is about output duplicates. And merge all of them into one dataset. This dataset will have : table name,primary keys. I think u are right on the point!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't.  You can make a new dataset.

```
data new;
  set old;
  dsname='NEW';
run;
```

You can use the INDSNAME option on the SET statement to tell you which dataset you are reading data from.

```
data new ;
   length indsname dsname $41 ;
   set old indsname=indsname ;
   dsname = indsname ;
run;
```

Makes more sense when the SET statement has more than one dataset referenced. You need to define two variables because the one defined by the INDSNAME= option is automatically dropped.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I will try it tomorrow when I get access to my database!