# how to append all tables with their table name in SAS

Tags: sql, macros, sas, append

I'm trying to append all the tables(same structure) in the work library into one data set. But I need to have a new column name which can indicate the table name.
I tried two methods:

1. macro array and do over:

   ```
   PROC APPEND BASE=_dupout DATA=dup_&dataset. FORCE;
   RUN;
   ```
2. Proc SQL:

   ```
   PROC SQL;
      SELECT MEMNAME, catx('.', libname, MEMNAME) INTO : MEMNAMES SEPARATED BY ' '     
      from dictionary.tables
      where libname='WORK';
   quit;

   DATA DUP_OUT;
      SET &MEMNAMES.;
   RUN;
   ```

but neither of those I can find a way add a new column (table name).  Maybe it is a very simple question? I'm stuck..please help...

Answer (score 1):

Very close, use the INDSNAME option in your SET statement.

```
DATA DUP_OUT;
SET &MEMNAMES. INDSNAME=SOURCE;
DSET=SOURCE;
RUN;
```

Comment: SAVE MY LIFE!! THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: You already had the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187021/how-to-put-the-name-of-a-dataset-as-a-column-in-sas